Flutter web only shows white screen
As the title says, when I try to run my flutter web app from android studio on chrome, I only see a white screen. It's been over half a year since I last worked on this project, I have already updated everything (flutter, dart, dependencies...).
I get this in the console output when running the app:
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:57531/eaZ7RkjmvoI=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57531/eaZ7RkjmvoI=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57531/eaZ7RkjmvoI=/ws
Rejecting promise with error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nativeCommunication')

A message on the flutter/lifecycle channel was discarded before it could be handled.
This happens when a plugin sends messages to the framework side before the framework has had an opportunity to register a listener. See the ChannelBuffers API documentation for details on how to configure the channel to expect more messages, or to expect messages to get discarded:
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ChannelBuffers-class.html
A message on the flutter/lifecycle channel was discarded before it could be handled.
This happens when a plugin sends messages to the framework side before the framework has had an opportunity to register a listener. See the ChannelBuffers API documentation for details on how to configure the channel to expect more messages, or to expect messages to get discarded:
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ChannelBuffers-class.html
A message on the flutter/lifecycle channel was discarded before it could be handled.
This happens when a plugin sends messages to the framework side before the framework has had an opportunity to register a listener. See the ChannelBuffers API documentation for details on how to configure the channel to expect more messages, or to expect messages to get discarded:
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ChannelBuffers-class.html
Application finished.

I even added some print lines at the very top of my main() which I didn't see in the output (see output above):
void main() async {
  debugPrint('debugPrint');
  log('log');
  // print('print'); // "Don't invoke 'print' in production code."
  ...

This is what I see in Chrome DevTools:

One potential solution that solved the problem for other people was to change a certain value in web/index.html.
I'm NOT planning to serve my web app in a path other than root (see here for more details), so I left this line in web/index.html the way it was:
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

This also didn't help:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
Building and running a release build also didn't work.
This is my pubspec.yaml:
name: my_app_name
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  #by flutter/google
  firebase_core: ^3.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^5.1.0
  cloud_functions: ^5.0.3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.3.0+3
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0

  provider: ^6.0.5

  #other
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_tts: ^4.0.2
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.6.0

  #...

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    #- assets/country_flags/
    - assets/learning_guide.png
    - assets/admin_learning_guide.png
    - lang/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

This is my output of flutter doctor -v:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.22.3 on channel stable at /Users/cedricdiederich/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0850beeb2 (13 days ago), 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 235db911ba
    • Dart version 3.4.4
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/cedricdiederich/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/cedricdiederich/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/cedricdiederich/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.73

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

OP, did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same with Flutter 3.24.1.

@cht in my case the issue was caused by the package html_editor_enhanced, it worked after I switched to a fork of that plugin (via github url in pubspec.yaml), see https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced/issues/523

I noticed this feature after upgrading from 3.19.6 to 3.24.3, the default renderer is now Canvas Kit and it seems to cause the issue, enforcing HTML rendering when launching my app solved the issue. FYI it also happen using wasm builds

First use Flutter doctor --version to know the current Dart version
then update this with the correct Dart version constraints and upgrade packages accordingly
environment:
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

more information here https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#sdk-constraints
